# Is there a good reference card that compares T-SQL and PL/SQL side-by-side?

Tags: database, postgresql, dml

I'm looking for a good reference card / cheat sheet that compares T-SQL and PL/SQL data manipulation language commands side-by-side.

I've previously searched SO but there isn't any older thread covering this particular subject so I thought it'd be a good idea to start one, given that such reference is almost mandatory if you happen to work in an environment where both technologies coexist.

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/) is pretty good. In ye olde paper and inke, [SQL in a nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565927445/) is also useful.

Comment: +1 for SQL in a Nutshell, which covers several other DBs also.

Comment: JUst waht I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [PDF](http://www.seouc.com/Presentations/OraclevsMSSQLSyntaxExamples.pdf) which goes into detail about syntax examples between the two:

Note: The PDF is from 2003 so it may not be update to date with new features from SQL Server 2005 or 2008 (such as the RowNum() function).

Comment: One I always fallow cheat sheet(Ref Cards) from here: https://dzone.com/refcardz